# JavaFX Move image animation

Tags: animation, javafx

How would I move an image across an AnchorPane in JavaFX? The image should move itself over a period of time. So far I have: (view is the ImageView already in the AnchorPane)

```
position = 35.0;
    for(int x = 0; x<11; x++){

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        myAnchorPane.getChildren().remove(view);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(view, position);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(view, 103.0);
        myAnchorPane.getChildren().add(view);
        position += 20;

    }
```

within the initialize() method of my controller. However, this does not work since the stage appears with the image already moved.

Comment: You should get the nodes current position in scene then set the nodes new position by adding the current position by some value(in your case 20).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class I create from an idea I got from tutoring a student.

> You should use Javafx animation. This moves with button press, but if you
>   want to see the diver move right, just remove the code from inside the isRightPressed if-statement and place it outside the if-statement. Also, remove this part: * (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation))).

```
import java.io.File;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class Diver {
    File diverFile;
    ImageView ivDiver = new ImageView();
    double rotation = 0.0;

    boolean isUpPressed, isDownPressed, isLeftPressed, isRightPressed;

    Diver()
    {
        diverFile = new File("src/img/diver.png");
        if(diverFile.exists())
        {
            Image diverImage = new Image(diverFile.toURI().toString());
            ivDiver.setImage(diverImage);
        } 

        ivDiver.setFocusTraversable(true);
        ivDiver.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                switch(event.getCode()) {
                    case UP: isUpPressed = true; break;
                    case DOWN: isDownPressed = true; break;
                    case LEFT: isLeftPressed = true; break;
                    case RIGHT: isRightPressed = true; break;
                }
            }
        });

        ivDiver.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                switch(event.getCode()) {
                    case UP: isUpPressed = false; break;
                    case DOWN: isDownPressed = false; break;
                    case LEFT: isLeftPressed = false; break;
                    case RIGHT: isRightPressed = false; break;
                }
            }        
        });    

        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer(){
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                if(isUpPressed){if(rotation == -360){rotation = 0;} ivDiver.setRotate(rotation+=5);}
                if(isDownPressed){if(rotation == 360){rotation = 0;} ivDiver.setRotate(rotation-=5);}
                if(isLeftPressed)
                {                    
                    ivDiver.setX(ivDiver.getX() - 2.0 * (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation))));
                    ivDiver.setY(ivDiver.getY() - 2.0 * (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation))));
                }
                if(isRightPressed)
                {
                    System.out.println("moving diver right!");
                    ivDiver.setX(ivDiver.getX() + 2.0 * (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation))));
                    ivDiver.setY(ivDiver.getY() + 2.0 * (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation))));
                }                    
            }

        };
        timer.start();
    }

    ImageView getDiver()
    {
        return ivDiver;
    }


}
```

You code may look something like this.

```
AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer(){
    @Override
    public void handle(long now) {
        System.out.println("moving diver right!");
        yourImageView.setX(yourImageView.getX() + 20.0 );
        //yourImageView.setY(yourImageView.getY() + 20.0 );                                      
    }
};
timer.start();
```